# Scroll when vim displays too much text

Tags: vim

If you enter `:function` in vim, a bunch of text scrolls past the screen. Is there any way to look through it?

I don't care about the specific output of `:function`.

Comment: @SPRBRN woops, fixed now

Comment: I see `more` at the end of the list, then press the spacebar and see the rest of the list.

Comment: The text should not be scrolling past. You should be seeing a "--more--" prompt at the bottom of the screen. At that prompt you can type `j`, `k` and a few other keys to scroll back and forth through the results. See `:help 'more'`. Do you have `set nomore` somewhere in your `~/.vimrc`?

Comment: @garyjohn, that was my issue.